# How to build the kryonet java library?

Tags: java, android, build, kryonet

I'm trying to use the kryonet networking library for an Android app and I would like to modify some of its behaviour to suit my needs.

I have cloned the appropriate [git repository](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet.git) on my machine, but did not find any instructions on how to build it.

Have any of you guys built kryonet from source before? If not, maybe you could point me in the right direction based on the repository found at the link above?

Comment: Dumping the source files and dependencies into the Android project is another option, albeit an ugly one.